# Excel - Split cell using regex in VBA, keep delimiter

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a row of cells in Excel that follow the following syntax:

*randomtext* VALUES (*randomnumber*, *randomtext*,

I have a VB script to split the text using regular expressions:

```
Public Function SplitRe(text As String, pattern As String, Optional ignorecase As Boolean) As String()
  Static re As Object
  If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.MultiLine = True
  End If
  re.ignorecase = ignorecase
  re.pattern = pattern
  SplitRe = Strings.Split(re.Replace(text, vbNullChar), vbNullChar)
End Function
```

The delimiter I'm using: `(VALUES)+(\s+)+(.)+\d+(,)`

This results in the text being split as:

*randomtext*

What I'm trying to achieve is to split the text after the script finds the delimiter, creating this:

*randomtext* VALUES (*randomnumber*,

But I can not find a way to properly augment my script to do so. Anyone see a solution?

Comment: Like your use of `VBScript.RegExp` as a **Static** object. Can you add sample data together with expected results?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't need RE for this, you could use Split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regular expressions neither splitting:

Faster:

```
 Left(text, InStrRev(text,",")) 'Truncate string after last comma
```

Safer (assuming `VALUES (` doesn't occur in first `randomtext`):

```
 Left(text, InStr(InStr(text,"VALUES ("),text,",")) 'Truncate string after comma which is after "VALUE ("
```

Comment: The *randomtext* before VALUES differs per row, and contains symbols '(' and ',' That's why I wanted to play it safe and use regex

Comment: and how would a your regex process `"VALUE (" VALUE (1.45, "some text"`?

Comment: I like your *Left(text, InStr(InStr(text,"VALUES ("),","))* solution, but somehow it's not giving me output.

Comment: Is `VALUES` case sensitive and space is regular space?

Comment: Case sensitive and regular space, yes

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much, been staring at my screen for a few hours, didn't catch it either! ;)